# Magic texture ignoring factor

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm making this vaporwave scene and was trying to make the purple part of the floor be visible, but mask out the black part to just be black without any texture. What am I doing wrong?

#### Node setup:

[image]

#### Scene:

[image]

[***Blend file***](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h23K1Cjc9qONtU4b2GhADy9DaXCMmjBq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: do you mean that the black checkers should be pitch black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but if you meant this, you can use this node setup:

[image]